# Put a string into a linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to do a LINQ expression where the expression varies on how deep the expected node is in the hierarchy.

So I use concat on a string like this:

```
var parString = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(".SelectMany(f => f.level)", level));
```

so if its 4 levels deep I get the string :

```
string1 = ".SelectMany(f => f.level).SelectMany(f => f.level).SelectMany(f => f.level).SelectMany(f => f.level)"
```

I then want to use this string in a LINQ expression, example:

```
List + string1 + .FirstOrDefault(.......);
```

Is this even possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Too much pseudo code, i don't get it. Why you need the strings there? What is your source, what are the variables, what is the expected result?

Comment: Why would you even put that in a string in the first place?

Comment: Even though I gave an answer below that I believe is what you meant please clarify what you're trying to do and why use strings? Are you using MoreLinq or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a for loop to determine how many times to call `.SelectMany`:

```
var query = List;
for(int depth = 4; depth > 0; depth--)
{
    query = query.SelectMany(f => f.level);
}
// Materialize query with `FirstOrDefault` or anything you need
```

Notice that currently if you reach the maximum depth and still continue you will get an exception. To solve that you can add an if statement to check that `f.level` is not null or not empty depending on your logic. Something like:

```
for(int depth = 4; depth > 0; depth--)
{
    query = query.SelectMany(f => f.level ?? Enumerable.Empty<YourType>());
}
```

Comment: Ok i will try to describe my problem further. I want to get an object from a certain depth. My Collection that I have to get this object from is a Collection that consist of objects that consists of objects and so on. If i just do SelectMany one time on the collection I can only get to the objects on the second level. If i do SelectMany().SelectMany (two times) i can get to the third level. So I need to have a general solution that works for all levels and i dont really know how to do

Comment: @coder2017 - then Please update question with this explanation and the solution above will do the trick for you